# Ruby each Iterator - Substitute the hash to iterate through based on if condition?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, foreach, ternary-operator

I have two hashes, and need to iterate through one of them based on the result of an if condition. Below is how my code currently looks:

```
if SOME CONDITION
  hash_a.each do |x|
    some code in here
  end
else 
  hash_b.each do |x|
    the same code in here
  end
```

There is about 30 lines of code executed for each element, so my question is: is there a way to make the code look something more like this:

```
SOME CONDITION ? hash_a.each do |x| : hash_b.each do |x|
  some code in here 
end
```

Or simplify/reduce it in any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you create a method with a hash as the argument. For example, `def doit(hash);  some code here; end`. Then execute `doit(condition ? hash_a : hash_b)`. This clarifies what you are doing and facilitates testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly select the object to call `each` on with a ternary operator, e.g.:

```
(SOME_CONDITION ? hash_a : hash_b).each do |x|
  # some code in here
end
```

If `SOME_CONDITION` is rather simple, this is a nice and clean approach. If the condition is more complex, you should either extract the condition or even the whole object selection into their own methods respectively.